# Is it possible to keep present Firefox add-ons by not updating?

Tags: firefox, updates, firefox-extensions

I know, I know, this used to be answered with a simple **yes**, I *know* that. But nowadays with the whole Webextensions disaster about to happen to Firefox, I wonder if it is still possible to avoid Firefox updates, because I've seen cases where **the automatic update** was TURNED OFF but somehow it still updated and it wasn't possible to get some add-ons and/or extensions back.

To clarify: this is a case where browser updates kill your add-ons.

Follow up question:
Is the only way to do this via the **Portable Firefox**-option?

Read this complaint by the developer of the popular Firefox add-on DownThemAll! why he is quitting Mozilla after 15 (!) years:

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WUbe6m0DXAEJ:www.downthemall.net/re-downthemall-and-webextensions-or-why-why-i-am-done-with-mozilla/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl&lr=lang_de%7Clang_en

Comment: Why do you want to disable Firefox updates? Just enable to accept the old legacy add-ons. See this [article](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/12/how-to-enable-legacy-extensions-in-firefox-57/).

Comment: Like you I have found the latest direction for Firefox diverges from my needs: the loss of Java was the final straw. I now use [Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/), which is a Firefox fork committed to supporting legacy add-ons and plug-ins in both the 32- and 64-bit versions. It supports most Firefox add-ons - some are in its own supported library, but most others in the [standard library](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/) work, though you may have to search for earlier versions compatible with Firefox 27. It needs a bit of effort, but I have found the transition worthwhile.

Comment: @biswa  I've got plans to use my browser past October:          "Legacy extension support will be dropped when the Beta version is updated to version 57 on October 10, 2017, and when the Release version of Firefox is updated to version 57 on November 14, 2017."

Comment: @AFH I stick with Firefox. Find alternative extension. Like I use unlock origin which have recently moved to WebExtension.

Comment: @biswa - There is no alternative for Java. While many web sites have removed it, devices like NAS discs and WebCams haven't.

Comment: @AFH well, the installer seems to be clean, at least https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/f4aff11976c588c62f965b3b06c855c25e123ad83edfce8a972901d8110e9200/detection

Comment: It looks like the link at the end of the question has gone dead.  Couldn't find an archived copy.  BTW, has this been overtaken by events now that V57 is out (assume your version either survived or didn't)?  If it's not too late (your old extensions should still be there in your profile, just not executable by V57), there are still a few options: 1) load the Firefox ESR version, which will buy you about a year.  2) I understand Waterfox is another Firefox fork that will run the legacy add-ons.